# Strip slashes on json array PHP

Tags: php, json

I have json string: `$json = '{ "comment" : "I don\'t like" }';`

```
$json_array = json_decode($json, true); // decode as array rather than object
```

Now the backslash before the single code mess up here:

```
foreach($json_array as $key => $value)
    {
        echo $value;
    }
```

so i tried this before `foreach` and decode:

```
$json = stripslashes($json);
```

But still gives an error:

> Error: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: There is no such thing as a JSON *array*. There are only JSON strings. Those strings can be converted to arrays or objects.

Comment: sorry about that i just did the shortcut version. update.

Comment: It would be better to paste your actual code and logged output. You have everyone guessing.

Comment: Yeah, your question is not clear. What's the error? What's it's message? Please define "Mess up". What does it mean when you say "make it work"? Okay at least you have posted an error message now I see.

Comment: Your code just works fine: http://codepad.org/h1DBVKzB No errors what's-o-ever.

Comment: @PHPNoob: For the error message just use the search. And please share which part of the error message you do not understand in specific.

Answer (score 1):

This is not legit PHP code:

```
$json = { "comment" : "I don\'t like" }
```

If you want a JSON *string* in PHP:

```
$json = '{ "comment" : "I don\'t like" }';
```

Comment: Sorry, what i did is a short cut illustration, its been updated now, you have any idea how to prevent the slash on producing error?

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert your json to an object or array by using [json_decode](http://php.net/json_decode). The following code outputs `I don't like`:

```
$json = '{ "comment" : "I don\'t like" }';
$data = json_decode($json, true);
foreach($data as $key => $value)
{
    echo $value;
}
```

Comment: Im sorry i should have completed the code. It's been update. thanks

Comment: Looks like OP updated and showed he's using both `json_decode()` and a properly formatted string (which was the heart of my answer).

Comment: actually in real case though, the array strings came from database, i don't know why it still produces an error.

Comment: @PHPNoob Can you edit your question with the output of `var_dump($json)` before and after the call to json_decode?